# Select first row each time column changes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in a postgres database, with 3 columns:

```
ReaderId: String
TagId: String
Timestamp: Timestamp

ReaderId  TagId  Timestamp
A         T1      20190101-00:00:00  *  ~      
A         T1      20190101-00:00:00     ~
A         T1      20190101-00:00:01    
A         T1      20190101-00:00:02   
B         T1      20190101-00:00:03  *
B         T1      20190101-00:00:03 
B         T1      20190101-00:00:04   
A         T1      20190101-00:00:05  * 
A         T1      20190101-00:00:06 
A         T1      20190101-00:00:07   
C         T1      20190101-00:00:08  *
C         T1      20190101-00:00:09   
B         T2      20190101-00:00:01  *
B         T2      20190101-00:00:04 
B         T2      20190101-00:00:05   
C         T2      20190101-00:00:06  *
C         T2      20190101-00:00:07   
B         T2      20190101-00:00:07  *   ~
B         T2      20190101-00:00:07      ~
B         T2      20190101-00:00:08
```

I would like a query/function that, when supplied with a TagId, returns the first row each time that tag is read at a different reader to which it was last read at (or the first row if the tag has never been read before). The rows which are eligible to be returned according to this criteria are highlighted by a * above. If there are multiple rows which are identical and 'equally first' then only one of these should be returned (as in the case of the rows marked with a ~ above).

This function needs to be performant as the volume of data is expected to easily grow into the many millions/low billions of rows. I can create any indexes required.

My SQL is rusty, and was never very good in the first place, so any help here is appreciated!

Comment: You're going to need a window function. Probably `LAG`. You'll probably need to use `LAG` in a subquery and then apply a filter in an outer query. I'm not sure indexes are going to help much; you pretty much have to do a full table scan here. Indexes are only helpful when you can exclude a lot of rows from consideration for your query or when they enable you to avoid a sort. I guess an index on the timestamp might avoid a sort, but you'll still have to scan billions of rows. You might need to consider creating some denormalized reporting tables that are updated periodically.

Comment: What decides the order of the first two rows with identical values? You need a tiebreaker or are you satisfied with an arbitrary pick? If so, does it matter if a different row is picked every other execution? (This may be important.)

Comment: For two rows with identical values, as far as I'm concerned the rows are identical so arbitrary is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) like others already suggested. But you specified:

> when supplied with a `TagId`

So you can simplify. A bit faster, too:

```
SELECT reader_id, tag_id, ts
FROM  (
   SELECT *, lag(reader_id) OVER (ORDER BY ts) IS DISTINCT FROM reader_id AS pick
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  tag_id = 'T1'  --  your tag_id here
   ) sub
WHERE  pick;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b2c474a5368461d0aa00fad6441a29fb)*

Also works for `NULL` values in the column `reader_id`.

You can wrap this in an SQL function or prepared statement and only pass your `tag_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(ReaderId) over (partition by TagId order by Timestamp) as prev_ReaderId
      from t
     ) t
where prev_ReaderId is null or prev_ReaderId <> ReaderId;
```

In Postgres, you can shorten the `where` clause to:

```
where prev_ReaderId is distinct from ReaderId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
select 
    reader_id, tag_id, timestamp
from (
    select
        reader_id, tag_id, timestamp,
        lag(reader_id) over (partition by tag_id order by timestamp)
    from my_table
    ) s
where lag is distinct from reader_id
order by tag_id, timestamp
```

Window functions are expensive but alternative solutions (if exist) rather cannot be cheaper. The index on `(tag_id, timestamp)` will support the query.

Online demo on [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0f79ae364989c817e89b1b8c0284db2a)

Read also about window functions [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)